# Getting TypeError: <type 'str'> from arcpy.mapping.ListLayers()?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, typeerror

I want to use ArcPy to turn on the labels for a layer.

I use this code but it fails and returns an error.

```
import arcpy   
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\P51\Desktop\testingLABEL.mxd") 
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "point10", "Layers")[0]  
layer.showLabels = True
```

This is the error :

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "<string>", line 4, in <module>   
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)   
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1517, in ListLayers
    result = mixins.MapDocumentMixin(map_document_or_layer).listLayers(wildcard, data_frame)   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 843, in listLayers
    raise TypeError(str(type(dataframe))) TypeError: <type 'str'>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I have many layers (100 layers/feature class/ file geodatabase) and I want to label those layers then I convert those layers into annotation and after that I convert them to DWG CAD (point and annotation), but I want to do that automatically (especially when do labeling and turn on those label), because it will be wasting time if labeling those 100 layers 1 by 1.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the [Syntax Help for ListLayers](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayers.htm#S2_GUID-40C6A4FF-6612-4782-B94D-63FFD68BCA79) you will see that its third parameter is `data_frame`:

```
ListLayers (map_document_or_layer, {wildcard}, {data_frame})
```

and that `data_frame` is expected to be:

> A variable that references a DataFrame object.

In your code you have:

```
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "point10", "Layers")[0]
```

so you are trying to set `data_frame` to a string instead of a DataFrame object.

Your code already has a DataFrame object created when you wrote:

```
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]
```

so all you need to do is to use that instead of the string:

```
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "point10", df)[0]
```